# Interface of a fragment in a new activity returns null for the first time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I tried to change [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097390/14007693) answer to send data from a fragment to a new activity. But `listener` gets null when activity starts.

I checked and after the first time activity starts, listener gets valued and works fine.
I know there are better ways to communicate between fragments and activities but for the sake of learning i want to do it this way. Thanks.

MapsFragment :

```
private static MapsFragment.onMySignalListener listener;
public void switchWindow() {
    if (listener == null)
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(listener != null){
        listener.onMySignal(paramImageUrl);
    }
}
public interface onMySignalListener {
    void onMySignal(String image_url);
}
public static void setOnMySignalListener(MapsFragment.onMySignalListener listener) {
    MapsFragment.listener = listener;
}
```

Destination Activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
MapsFragment.setOnMySignalListener(new MapsFragment.onMySignalListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMySignal(String image_url) {
            ImageUrl = image_url;
        }
    });
}
```

somewhere in a button listener in the fragment i call this method

```
switchWindow();
```